# Tengo un service worker en mi pagina wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

tengo una pagina y tengo un service worker que funciona hasta cuardo los archivos en cache pero cuando los pongo offline no me muestra los archivos en caches

index llamando al sw.js

```js
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
     window.addEventListener('load', function() {
       navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(registration) {
         // Si es exitoso
         console.log('SW registrado correctamente');
       }, function(err) {
         // Si falla
         console.log('SW fallo', err);
       });
     });
  }
```

hasta se ejecuta bien y ahora ejecuta el sw

```js
var nameapp = 'AppService_woker'     
var versions = 'version_01'             
var CACHE_NAME = nameapp + versions
var URLS = [                            
  './',             
  './index.html',
  './sw.js',          
  './manifiesto.json'
]

// Responder con recursos en caché
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (e) {
  console.log('fetch request : ' + e.request.url)
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function (request) {
      if (request) { // Si el caché está disponible, responda con caché
        console.log('Respondiendo al Cache : ' + e.request.url)
        return request
      } else {       // Si no hay caché, intente recuperar la solicitud
        console.log('Los Archivos no se han guardado en cache : ' + e.request.url)
        return fetch(e.request)
      }

      // Puede omitir si / else para console.log y poner una línea debajo también como esto.
      // return request || fetch(e.request)
    })
  )
})


// Recursos de Cache
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
      console.log('Instalando en Cache : ' + CACHE_NAME)
      return cache.addAll(URLS)
    })
  )
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]